# update_attributes using breadcrumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a status enum in my model:

```
enum status: [ :draft, :pending, :accepted, :reoffered, :rejected ]
```

and I am changing it from a form like this:

```
<%= f.input :status, as: :select, collection: Offer.statuses.keys.to_a %>
```

Can you give me a hint on how to be able to change the status directly from the index view, using clickable breadcrumbs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Draft", offer_path(:id => offer.id, "offer[status]" => "draft"), method: :put, :action => "update" %>
            <span class="divider">/</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Pending", offer_path(:id => offer.id, "offer[status]" => "pending"), method: :put, :action => "update" %>
            <span class="divider">/</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Accepted", offer_path(:id => offer.id, "offer[status]" => "accepted"), method: :put, :action => "update" %>
            <span class="divider">/</span>
          </li>

</div>
```